# Google Play: Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key

Tags: flutter, google-play, keystore, android-keystore

Since I had to upgrade to Flutter 2 I decided to start a new project with null safety and move my lib folder to it. I also moved my `keystore` (this was always store in my repo as well so I never lost it).

After many changes (more than 500 thanks Flutter team) I pushed a new appbundle to Google Play and got this message:

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your
> App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your
> app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with
> fingerprint: SHA1: A but the certificate used to sign the app bundle
> that you uploaded has fingerprint: SHA1: B

I always had SHA1 A for everything. So I went to my old Flutter 1 branch, downgraded Flutter version and ran this:

```
keytool -keystore assets/.keystore -list -v
```

**Again, SHA1 A was shown**. I even compiled from this again but... not I didn't get any error message.

Why is this?

I also tried in new branch copying old key (which again, it's the same) and got also the error

Answer (score 1):

I did not copy ios or android folder and the last one I was missing the keystore also inside of it and do some changes for the `build.gradle`. I could share it but I guess everyone could have different config here. Just keep on mind that this could point as well to the keystore like:

```
release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
```